# Property "0" does not have corresponding setter in class "Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderPaymentInterface"

Tags: magento-2.1, rest-api

I am trying to update the `sales_order_item` table in Magento 2.1.9 using REST API /V1/orders/create PUT, but it gives the error 'Internal Error. Details are available in Magento log file.'.

In the log file the issue is "Property "0" does not have corresponding setter in class".

The JSON which I am posting:

```
{
  "entity": {
    "items": [
      {
        "additional_data": "null",
        "amount_refunded": 0,
        "applied_rule_ids": null,
        "base_amount_refunded": 0,
        "base_cost": 0,
        "base_discount_amount": 0,
        "base_discount_invoiced": 0,
        "base_discount_refunded": 0,
        "base_discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
        "base_discount_tax_compensation_invoiced": 0,
        "base_discount_tax_compensation_refunded": 0,
        "base_original_price": 0,
        "base_price": 0,
        "base_price_incl_tax": 0,
        "base_row_invoiced": 0,
        "base_row_total": 0,
        "base_row_total_incl_tax": 0,
        "base_tax_amount": 0,
        "base_tax_before_discount": 0,
        "base_tax_invoiced": 0,
        "base_tax_refunded": 0,
        "base_weee_tax_applied_amount": 0,
        "base_weee_tax_applied_row_amnt": 0,
        "base_weee_tax_disposition": 0,
        "base_weee_tax_row_disposition": 0,
        "created_at": null,
        "description": null,
        "discount_amount": 0,
        "discount_invoiced": 0,
        "discount_percent": 0,
        "discount_refunded": 0,
        "event_id": 0,
        "ext_order_item_id": null,
        "free_shipping": 0,
        "gw_base_price": 0,
        "gw_base_price_invoiced": 0,
        "gw_base_price_refunded": 0,
        "gw_base_tax_amount": 0,
        "gw_base_tax_amount_invoiced": 0,
        "gw_base_tax_amount_refunded": 0,
        "gw_id": 0,
        "gw_price": 0,
        "gw_price_invoiced": 0,
        "gw_price_refunded": 0,
        "gw_tax_amount": 0,
        "gw_tax_amount_invoiced": 0,
        "gw_tax_amount_refunded": 0,
        "discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
        "discount_tax_compensation_canceled": 0,
        "discount_tax_compensation_invoiced": 0,
        "discount_tax_compensation_refunded": 0,
        "is_qty_decimal": 0,
        "is_virtual": 0,
        "item_id": 184,
        "locked_do_invoice": 0,
        "locked_do_ship": 0,
        "name": null,
        "no_discount": 0,
        "order_id": 0,
        "original_price": 0,
        "parent_item_id": 0,
        "price": 0,
        "price_incl_tax": 0,
        "product_id": 0,
        "product_type": null,
        "qty_backordered": 0,
        "qty_canceled": 0,
        "qty_invoiced": 0,
        "qty_ordered": 0,
        "qty_refunded": 0,
        "qty_returned": 0,
        "qty_shipped": 0,
        "quote_item_id": 0,
        "row_invoiced": 0,
        "row_total": 0,
        "row_total_incl_tax": 0,
        "row_weight": 0,
        "sku": "82test05",
        "store_id": 0,
        "tax_amount": 0,
        "tax_before_discount": 0,
        "tax_canceled": 0,
        "tax_invoiced": 0,
        "tax_percent": 0,
        "tax_refunded": 0,
        "updated_at": null,
        "weee_tax_applied": null,
        "weee_tax_applied_amount": 0,
        "weee_tax_applied_row_amount": 0,
        "weee_tax_disposition": 0,
        "weee_tax_row_disposition": 0,
        "weight": 0,
        "product_option": null
      }
    ],
    "payment": [
      {
        "account_status": null,
        "additional_data": null,
        "additional_information": null,
        "address_status": null,
        "amount_authorized": 0,
        "amount_canceled": 0,
        "amount_ordered": 0,
        "amount_paid": 0,
        "amount_refunded": 0,
        "anet_trans_method": null,
        "base_amount_authorized": 0,
        "base_amount_canceled": 0,
        "base_amount_ordered": 0,
        "base_amount_paid": 0,
        "base_amount_paid_online": 0,
        "base_amount_refunded": 0,
        "base_amount_refunded_online": 0,
        "base_shipping_amount": 0,
        "base_shipping_captured": 0,
        "base_shipping_refunded": 0,
        "cc_approval": null,
        "cc_avs_status": null,
        "cc_cid_status": null,
        "cc_debug_request_body": null,
        "cc_debug_response_body": null,
        "cc_debug_response_serialized": null,
        "cc_exp_month": null,
        "cc_exp_year": null,
        "cc_last4": null,
        "cc_number_enc": null,
        "cc_owner": null,
        "cc_secure_verify": null,
        "cc_ss_issue": null,
        "cc_ss_start_month": null,
        "cc_ss_start_year": null,
        "cc_status": null,
        "cc_status_description": null,
        "cc_trans_id": null,
        "cc_type": null,
        "echeck_account_name": null,
        "echeck_account_type": null,
        "echeck_bank_name": null,
        "echeck_routing_number": null,
        "echeck_type": null,
        "entity_id": 0,
        "last_trans_id": null,
        "method": "checkmo",
        "parent_id": 0,
        "po_number": null,
        "protection_eligibility": null,
        "quote_payment_id": 0,
        "shipping_amount": 0,
        "shipping_captured": 0,
        "shipping_refunded": 0
      }
    ],
    "adjustment_negative": 0,
    "adjustment_positive": 0,
    "applied_rule_ids": null,
    "base_adjustment_negative": 0,
    "base_adjustment_positive": 0,
    "base_currency_code": null,
    "base_discount_amount": 0,
    "base_discount_canceled": 0,
    "base_discount_invoiced": 0,
    "base_discount_refunded": 0,
    "base_grand_total": 0,
    "base_discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
    "base_discount_tax_compensation_invoiced": 0,
    "base_discount_tax_compensation_refunded": 0,
    "base_shipping_amount": 0,
    "base_shipping_canceled": 0,
    "base_shipping_discount_amount": 0,
    "base_shipping_discount_tax_compensation_amnt": 0,
    "base_shipping_incl_tax": 0,
    "base_shipping_invoiced": 0,
    "base_shipping_refunded": 0,
    "base_shipping_tax_amount": 0,
    "base_shipping_tax_refunded": 0,
    "base_subtotal": 0,
    "base_subtotal_canceled": 0,
    "base_subtotal_incl_tax": 0,
    "base_subtotal_invoiced": 0,
    "base_subtotal_refunded": 0,
    "base_tax_amount": 0,
    "base_tax_canceled": 0,
    "base_tax_invoiced": 0,
    "base_tax_refunded": 0,
    "base_total_canceled": 0,
    "base_total_due": 0,
    "base_total_invoiced": 0,
    "base_total_invoiced_cost": 0,
    "base_total_offline_refunded": 0,
    "base_total_online_refunded": 0,
    "base_total_paid": 0,
    "base_total_qty_ordered": 0,
    "base_total_refunded": 0,
    "base_to_global_rate": 0,
    "base_to_order_rate": 0,
    "billing_address_id": 0,
    "can_ship_partially": 0,
    "can_ship_partially_item": 0,
    "coupon_code": null,
    "created_at": null,
    "customer_dob": null,
    "customer_email": null,
    "customer_firstname": null,
    "customer_gender": 0,
    "customer_group_id": 0,
    "customer_id": 0,
    "customer_is_guest": 0,
    "customer_lastname": null,
    "customer_middlename": null,
    "customer_note": null,
    "customer_note_notify": 0,
    "customer_prefix": null,
    "customer_suffix": null,
    "customer_taxvat": null,
    "discount_amount": 0,
    "discount_canceled": 0,
    "discount_description": null,
    "discount_invoiced": 0,
    "discount_refunded": 0,
    "edit_increment": 0,
    "email_sent": 0,
    "entity_id": 0,
    "ext_customer_id": null,
    "ext_order_id": null,
    "forced_shipment_with_invoice": 0,
    "global_currency_code": null,
    "grand_total": 0,
    "discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
    "discount_tax_compensation_invoiced": 0,
    "discount_tax_compensation_refunded": 0,
    "hold_before_state": null,
    "hold_before_status": null,
    "increment_id": null,
    "is_virtual": 0,
    "order_currency_code": null,
    "original_increment_id": null,
    "payment_authorization_amount": 0,
    "payment_auth_expiration": 0,
    "protect_code": null,
    "quote_address_id": 0,
    "quote_id": 0,
    "relation_child_id": null,
    "relation_child_real_id": null,
    "relation_parent_id": null,
    "relation_parent_real_id": null,
    "remote_ip": null,
    "shipping_amount": 0,
    "shipping_canceled": 0,
    "shipping_description": null,
    "shipping_discount_amount": 0,
    "shipping_discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
    "shipping_incl_tax": 0,
    "shipping_invoiced": 0,
    "shipping_refunded": 0,
    "shipping_tax_amount": 0,
    "shipping_tax_refunded": 0,
    "state": null,
    "status": null,
    "store_currency_code": null,
    "store_id": 0,
    "store_name": null,
    "store_to_base_rate": 0,
    "store_to_order_rate": 0,
    "subtotal": 0,
    "subtotal_canceled": 0,
    "subtotal_incl_tax": 0,
    "subtotal_invoiced": 0,
    "subtotal_refunded": 0,
    "tax_amount": 0,
    "tax_canceled": 0,
    "tax_invoiced": 0,
    "tax_refunded": 0,
    "total_canceled": 0,
    "total_due": 0,
    "total_invoiced": 0,
    "total_item_count": 0,
    "total_offline_refunded": 0,
    "total_online_refunded": 0,
    "total_paid": 0,
    "total_qty_ordered": 0,
    "total_refunded": 0,
    "updated_at": null,
    "weight": 0,
    "x_forwarded_for": null,
    "billing_address": null,
    "status_histories": null
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post the data you are sending

Comment: can you specify the magento version ?

Comment: I am using magento 2.1.9.